# How to rename PHPSESSID?

Tags: php

Wondering how I can change the php session id from PHPSESSID to something else so that it does not interfere with other PHP scripts running on the same domain. Is this possible?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 43, accepted):

See this link for [PHP runtime configuration](http://se.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name). The variable you are looking for is *session.name*. You can also alter this programmatically by calling [session_name](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) before any call to [session_start](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) or [session_register](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php).

Answer (score 45):

```
session_name('mySessionName');
session_start();
```

Try looking at [PHP's reference](http://php.net/session).