# how can i hide this name PHPSESSID and give it another name?

Tags: session, cookies

I created a small blog with php & MySQL, when i check the cookies section, i see

nameofmywebsite:
PHPSESSID:
value like: e7b80edc9d127a3a47cfe885efe2351f

i don't see anything else.

here is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$log = session_id();
?>
```

thanks

Comment: `session_name('name');
session_start();`

Comment: Actually, this question already was asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964272/how-to-rename-phpsessid

Comment: Are you asking to rename `PHPSESSID` or change the ID value `e7b80edc9d127a3a47cfe885efe2351f`? In either case, what is the reason you want to do that? Short answer: no, you can't hide it; there has to be something unique and identifiable that the browser and server can use to verify each other, and anything the browser can see can also be seen by the browser user. As for renaming it, well, yes, you can... but there's unlikely to be any good reason for doing so.

Comment: Spudley => you are right, the reason is, i installed sitelock on my website, i'm getting alerts that i'm vulnerable, and "if you do not recognize a cookie name it may be worth investigating" i'm asking myself: how can i fix that.