# Symfony session (stand alaone) cookiename

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-foundation

I use the Symfony http foundation stand alone (aka i installed the http-foundation package with composer inside my non-symfony project). Ik would like to change the name of the session cookie. What would be my best way to achieve this?

I read a lot of items regarding this issue, most of them are about configuring the cookie name in the Symfony config.yml settings file which i do not have (stand-alone usage).

Any tips?

Comment: just use the `construct` to configure: name, lifetime, domain, path ect look at [the api][1]


  [1]: http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Cookie.html#method___construct

Comment: Thank! I would use this function to set a new cookie! But can i also use this to change the name of the cookie used for session? I mean the cookie with the name 'PHPSESSID'. If true, i'm not sure how to.

Comment: Just plain php, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964272/how-to-rename-phpsessid

Comment: That did the trick! I did not think this was a plain PHP issue. Was searching in the complete wrong corner :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Session::setName()` instead of `session_name()`.

See this [here](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) for Symfony 5.3 and [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html) for Symfony 6 & more

Comment: Thanks but the page leads to 404