# How can I hide PHPSESSID cookie like facebook and other big sites?

Tags: php, session, web, cookies

How can I hide the PHPSESSID cookie? When I set session.use_cookies to 0 in php.ini, I can't use the sessions. Sites like Facebook does'nt show PHPSESSID cookie but when I redirect a file using code - header('Location: https://facebook.com/cookie?'.$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']); - to Facebook to get sessionid from url and i get the session id. Give me the reason.

Comment: maybe they are using something other than php?

Comment: The session cookie can be named anything, and other approaches like JWT stored in the browser's LocalStorage are possible. Why do you *want* to hide the cookie? There are better ways to prevent [session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking#Prevention).

Comment: Maybe it is good to read <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964272/how-to-rename-phpsessid>

Comment: my question is to you ceejayoz. I just want to ask how facebook hides the PHPSESSID cookie?

Comment: @Mr.Sinha They didn't hide it - they set several cookies that look like they're session-related. I see cookies like `sb`, `presence`, etc. (It's also likely they have something a little more complicated than a single session per user, given all the backend systems they have.) You're going to have to have *some* sort of session cookie, but you can rename it to something that's less obviously the default.

Answer (score 2):

You can't hide the session cookie as it is essential for the session management. But you could change the name of the session cookie with the [`session_name`](http://php.net/session_name) function.