Apache2.4 with two versions of php session sharing
I have seen many articles regarding session sharing between subdomains, and I can't quite make things work.
Setup:
Localhost - Apache2.4 with vhosts - 2 domains (one of which is top level domain, and one a sub-domain)
Top level domain is using php5.3 (yes, I know we need to get off of that), raw coded php
Sub-domain is using 8.x and CodeIgniter4
Logging into CodeIgniter site session cookie is generated with PHPSESSID as name.  Logging into php5.3 site after, the php encoded site generates another session cookie with the same name (although instead of PHPSESSIDxxx, it is sess_xxx where xxx is the same).  Both session cookies are being to same location, but the fact that there are 2, suggests there is no access between them.
Anyone have any ideas?  I have tried pretty much everything that I've found on-line, including CodeIgniter settings, php_ini settings (in php.ini and calls in php before session call).
Okay, set up two dummy sites (one with php8 to test if php5 was the issue) and added a script to each -
session_name('PHPSESSID');
session_start();

$_SESSION['system'][] = 'php8.php5.com'; // the other script 'php.com'

echo session_name();

var_dump($_SESSION);

Results - the session cookies both came back with the prefix sess_ in the actual server folder itself.  Although the code above calling for session name showed PHPSESSID.  So, that was part of my misunderstanding.  I guess the server/php saves the name in the session itself regardless of what it is called externally.  Additionally, the session variables aggregated as expected.  So, the issue appears to be caused by something in CodeIgniter4.
Anyone know how to get codeigniter sessions to play nice with homerolled php sessions?

I think you just need to set the PHP session name to use the same value? https://stackoverflow.com/q/964272/231316

I am using the same session id name in both sites.  They, however, display with different names. php ini:  ; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
; http://php.net/session.name
session.name = PHPSESSID     CodeIgniter4 - app/config/Session.php  /**
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Session Cookie Name
* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
*
* The session cookie name, must contain only [0-9a-z_-] characters
*/
public string $cookieName = 'PHPSESSID';

Are you certain that those examples work with diverging PHP versions? there are many php versions between the two you mention. I would raise the "wary" flag - 5.X is end of service - no security patches, so trying to carry over sessions seems like a horrible idea. The only thing I can think of is creating a custom session handler, and ensuring that it is implemented for both versions - either with a database (m2 or sqlite is sufficient) - or a file based session handler.

@Robert please [edit] your question when providing supplemental information...

The fact that the cookie name is not changing tells me that something isn't working or being set correctly.

could you provide a dockerfile or vagrantfile or some more details about your setup, so it can be reproduced? ie os version, if windows, then if you are using xamp/other, etc

I assume that your CI project use the Session class. If so, I think the easiest way would be to inject CodeIgniter into your PHP5.x project so that the session management is the same in both projects. I doubt that CI still has support for PHP5 and you may run into issues that even an older CI implementation for PHP5.x may not be compatible with the version you are running now.
You might also look at the CI session handling to see If you can create something yourself, based on that implementation, which you could use to make the sessions merge.
Some things for you to consider:
It is unclear why you want to keep the legacy 5.x project. I am assuming that it is a legacy project which you are in the process of upgrading, trying to get the new stuff to work as an intermediary fix.

Consider if Session Syncing is the best approach:

PHP5 is not receiving security patches
Unpatched flaws in php5 may grant an attacker access to your modern application


Depending on your use case maybe an NGINX in front acting as a gateway/load balancer, and managing the sessions, potentially ensuring that your upstream services are reachable with a common session, and with rules set up so that common traffic is directed to the CI application.
Consider adding mod_security as a WAF (web application firewall) at least on your PHP5.x application and potentially on your CI application as well.
Again without knowing what the actual situation is, if you are having a lot of trouble figuring it out, and issues with sensitivity causing you to hesitate exposing information to a bunch of anonymous dudes on the internet (here), consider hiring a consultant with the specific task of analyzing your business requirements, and designing a solution that will meet your requirements.
And make sure that you state your end goal, causing you to try mixing out-of-support sessions with modern, supported versions It may seem pricey, but sometimes, especially if you are a solo developer, a second opinion is priceless.

